# matching and counting strings (k-mer of DNA) in R

Tags: regex, r, string, dna-sequence

I have a list of strings (DNA sequence) including A,T,C,G. I want to find all matches and insert into table whose columns are all possible combination of those DNA alphabet (4^k; "k" is length of each match - K-mer - and must be specified by user) and rows represent number of matches in sequence in a list.

Lets say my list includes 5 members:

```
DNAlst<-list("CAAACTGATTTT","GATGAAAGTAAAATACCG","ATTATGC","TGGA","CGCGCATCAA")
```

I want set `k=2` (2-mer) so `4^2=16` combination are available including `AA,AT,AC,AG,TA,TT,...`

So my table will have `5 rows` and `16 columns`. I want to count number of matches between my k-mers and list members.

My desired result: `df:`

```
lstMemb AA AT AC AG TA TT TC ...
  1     2  1  1  0  0  3  0
  2       ...
  3
  4
  5
```

Could you help me implement this in R?

Comment: my database is huge, so efficiency is also important here. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for speed the obvious solution is [`stringi`](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/) package. 
There is `stri_count_fixed` function for counting patterns.
And now, check the code and benchmark!

```
DNAlst<-list("CAAACTGATTTT","GATGAAAGTAAAATACCG","ATTATGC","TGGA","CGCGCATCAA")
dna <- stri_paste(rep(c("A","C","G","T"),each=4),c("A","C","G","T"))
result <- t(sapply(DNAlst, stri_count_fixed,pattern=dna,overlap=TRUE))
colnames(result) <- dna
result
     AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT
[1,]  2  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  3
[2,]  5  1  1  2  0  1  1  0  2  0  0  1  2  0  1  0
[3,]  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
[4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
[5,]  1  0  0  1  2  0  2  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0



fstri <- function(x){
    t(sapply(x, stri_count_fixed,dna,T))
}
fbio <- function(x){
    t(sapply(x, function(x){x1 <-  DNAString(x); oligonucleotideFrequency(x1,2)}))
}

all(fstri(DNAlst)==fbio(DNAlst)) #results are the same
[1] TRUE

longDNA <- sample(DNAlst,100,T)
microbenchmark(fstri(longDNA),fbio(longDNA))
Unit: microseconds
           expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
 fstri(longDNA)    689.378    738.184    825.3014    766.862    793.134   6027.039   100
  fbio(longDNA) 118371.825 125552.401 129543.6585 127245.489 129165.711 359335.294   100
127245.489/766.862
## [1] 165.9301
```

**Ca 165x times faster** :)

Answer (score 7):

May be this helps

```
 source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
 biocLite("Biostrings")
 library(Biostrings)
 t(sapply(DNAlst, function(x){x1 <-  DNAString(x)
                   oligonucleotideFrequency(x1,2)}))
  #     AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT
  #[1,]  2  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  3
  #[2,]  5  1  1  2  0  1  1  0  2  0  0  1  2  0  1  0
  #[3,]  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
  #[4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
  #[5,]  1  0  0  1  2  0  2  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Or as suggested by @Arun, convert the `list` to `vector` first

```
   oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAStringSet(unlist(DNAlst)), 2L)
   #     AA AC AG AT CA CC CG CT GA GC GG GT TA TC TG TT
   #[1,]  2  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  3
   #[2,]  5  1  1  2  0  1  1  0  2  0  0  1  2  0  1  0
   #[3,]  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
   #[4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
   #[5,]  1  0  0  1  2  0  2  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: You should do: `oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAStringSet(x), 2L)`, where `x` is `unlist(DNAlist)`!!

Answer (score 6):

We recently released our 'kebabs' package as part of the Bioconductor 
3.0 release. Though this package is aimed at providing sequence kernels 
for classification, regression, and other tasks such as similarity-based 
clustering, the package includes functionality for computing k-mer frequencies efficiently, too:

```
#installing kebabs:
#source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
#biocLite(c("kebabs", "Biostrings"))
library(kebabs)

s1 <- DNAString("ATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGACTGACTAGCTAGCTACGATCGACTG")
s1
s2 <- DNAString(paste0(rep(s1, 200), collate=""))
s2

sk13 <- spectrumKernel(k=13, normalized=FALSE)
system.time(kmerFreq <- drop(getExRep(s1, sk13)))
kmerFreq
system.time(kmerFreq <- drop(getExRep(s2, sk13)))
kmerFreq
```

So you see that the k-mer frequencies are obtained as the explicit 
feature vector of the standard (unnormalized) spectrum kernel with k=13. 
This function is implemented in highly efficient C++ code that builds up 
a prefix tree and only considers k-mers that actually occur in the 
sequence (as you requested). You see that even for k=13 and a sequence 
with tens of thousands of bases, the computations only take fractions of 
a second (19 msecs on our 5-year-old Dell server). The above function 
also works for DNAStringSets, but, in this case, you should remove the 
drop() to get a matrix of k-mer frequencies. The matrix is by default 
sparse (class 'dgRMatrix'), but you can also enforce the result to be in 
standard dense matrix format (however, still omitting k-mers that do not 
occur at all in any of the sequences):

```
sv <- c(DNAStringSet(s1), DNAStringSet(s2))
system.time(kmerFreq <- getExRep(sv, sk13))
kmerFreq
system.time(kmerFreq <- getExRep(sv, sk13, sparse=FALSE))
kmerFreq
```

How long the k-mers may be, may depend on your system. On our system, 
the limit seems to be k=22 for DNA sequences. The same works for RNA and 
amino acid sequences. For the latter, however, the limits in terms of k 
are significantly lower, since the feature space is obviously much 
larger for the same k.

```
#for the kebabs documentation please see:
browseVignettes("kebabs")
```

I hope that helps. If you have any further questions, please let me know.

Best regards,
Ulrich

Comment: thanks for explicit answer. one question about normalization in `spectrumKernel(k=13, normalized=TRUE)`; does it normalize rowwise or columnwise?

Comment: Kernel normalization is defined as k'(x, y) = k(x, y) / sqrt(k(x, x) * k(y, y)). In the case of the explicit representation, this corresponds to rowwise normalization by dividing each row by its Euclidean norm. If you need columnwise normalization, compute the explicit representation without normalization (as in my answer above) and apply scale() to the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

My answer wasn't as fast as @bartektartanus. However, it is also pretty fast and I wrote the code... :D

### The plus side of my code when compared to the others is:

1. Don't need to install the unimplemented version of `stri_count_fixed`
2. Probably `stringi` package will get really slow for big k-mers since it 
   has to generate all possible combinations for pattern and afterwards,
   check their existence in the data and count how many times it appears.
3. It also works for long **single** and and **multiple** sequences with 
   the same output really fast.
4. You can put a value for `k` instead of creating a pattern string.
5. If you run `oligonucleotideFrequency` with a `k` bigger than 12
   in a big sequence, the function freezes for excess of memory use and
   R is restarted, while with my function it runs pretty fast.

### My code

```
sequence_kmers <- function(sequence, k){
    k_mers <- lapply(sequence,function(x){
        seq_loop_size <- length(DNAString(x))-k+1

        kmers <- sapply(1:seq_loop_size, function(z){
            y <- z + k -1
            kmer <- substr(x=x, start=z, stop=y)
            return(kmer)
        })
        return(kmers)
    })

    uniq <- unique(unlist(k_mers))
    ind <- t(sapply(k_mers, function(x){
        tabulate(match(x, uniq), length(uniq))
    }))
    colnames(ind) <- uniq

    return(ind)
}
```

I use the `Biostrings`package only to count the bases... you can use other options like `stringi` to count...
if you remove all code below `k_mers lapply` and `return(k_mers)` it returns just the list... of all k-mers with the respective repeated vectors

#### `sequence` here is a sequence of 1000bp

```
#same output for 1 or multiple sequences
> sequence_kmers(sequence,4)[,1:10]
GTCT TCTG CTGA TGAA GAAC AACG ACGC CGCG GCGA CGAG 
   4    4    3    4    4    8    6    4    5    5 
> sequence_kmers(c(sequence,sequence),4)[,1:10]
     GTCT TCTG CTGA TGAA GAAC AACG ACGC CGCG GCGA CGAG
[1,]    4    4    3    4    4    8    6    4    5    5
[2,]    4    4    3    4    4    8    6    4    5    5
```

**Tests done with my function:**

```
#super fast for 1 sequence
> system.time({sequence_kmers(sequence,13)})
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
     0.08      0.00      0.08 

#works fast for 1 sequence or 50 sequences of 1000bps
> system.time({sequence_kmers(rep(sequence,50),4)})
     user    system   elapsed
     3.61      0.00      3.61 

#same speed for 3-mers or 13-mers
> system.time({sequence_kmers(rep(sequence,50),13)})
     user    system   elapsed
     3.63      0.00      3.62
```

**Tests done with `Biostrings`:**

```
#Slow 1 sequence 12-mers
> system.time({oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAString(sequence),12)})
     user    system   elapsed 
   150.11      1.14    151.37 

#Biostrings package freezes for a single sequence of 13-mers
> system.time({oligonucleotideFrequency(sequence,13)})  
freezes, used all my 8gb RAM
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

```
DNAlst<-list("CAAACTGATTTT","GATGAAAGTAAAATACCG","ATTATGC","TGGA","CGCGCATCAA","ACACACACACCA")
len <- 4
stri_sub_fun <- function(x) table(stri_sub(x,1:(stri_length(x)-len+1),length = len))
sapply(DNAlst, stri_sub_fun)
[[1]]

AAAC AACT ACTG ATTT CAAA CTGA GATT TGAT TTTT 
   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 

[[2]]

AAAA AAAG AAAT AAGT AATA ACCG AGTA ATAC ATGA GAAA GATG GTAA TAAA TACC TGAA 
   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 

[[3]]

ATGC ATTA TATG TTAT 
   1    1    1    1 

[[4]]

TGGA 
   1 

[[5]]

ATCA CATC CGCA CGCG GCAT GCGC TCAA 
   1    1    1    1    1    1    1 

[[6]]

ACAC ACCA CACA CACC 
   4    1    3    1
```