# Using stri_count_fixed with overlap=TRUE returning an error of Incorrect number of arguments

Tags: regex, r, string, dna-sequence, stringi

Today I saw a new post regarding a new add to the stringi package where you would be able to add the argument `"overlap=TRUE"` to some of the stringi search functions.

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600735/matching-and-counting-strings-k-mer-of-dna-in-r/26640055#26640055).

However, I've tried the exact code that bartektartanus suggested (from installing to the example), and when I run it I get an error of **Incorrect number of arguments (3), expecting 2 for 'stri_count_fixed'**

```
> library("stringi", lib.loc="D:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.1.1/library")
> DNAlst<-list("CAAACTGATTTT","GATGAAAGTAAAATACCG","ATTATGC","TGGA","CGCGCATCAA")
> dna <- stri_paste(rep(c("A","C","G","T"),each=4),c("A","C","G","T"))
> result <- t(sapply(DNAlst, stri_count_fixed,pattern=dna,overlap=TRUE))
Error in .Call("stri_count_fixed", str, pattern, overlap, PACKAGE = "stringi") : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (3), expecting 2 for 'stri_count_fixed'
> colnames(result) <- dna
Error in colnames(result) <- dna : object 'result' not found
```

I'm wondering if this is because this is something really new, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Devtools version: 1.6
Stringi version: 0.3-1
R version = 3.1.1 (RRO 8.0 beta)
64bits running on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happened because R was trying to find Rtools, but it couldn't. The system shortcut was wrong. And you need Rtools for the proper execution of `devtools`.
The sad thing is that I figured out this when I was doing something completely unrelated even with Rtools and `devtools` lol...

```
> library("devtools", lib.loc="D:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.1.1/library")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but the version of Rtools previously
installed in F:/Program Files/Rtools has been deleted.
```

After re-installing Rtools from this [cran link](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), the program worked as it was supposed to.

However, the installation of this version of `stringi`took almost half an hour to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably installed it wrong. There is separate branch for this overlap. New stringi version 0.3 is goning to be released soon and overlap is not included yet :) But it will be with 0.4 version, when we test it properly. So for now on, install it from this branch: `fixed_overlap`

```
library('devtools') # call install.packages('devtools') first
install_github('Rexamine/stringi', ref = "fixed_overlap")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've run this exact code:
   install.packages('devtools'); library('devtools'); install_github('Rexamine/stringi', ref = "fixed_overlap"). Just as you mentioned.
I even tried to uninstall stringi and devtools, and it keeps installing stringi v.0.3, any other suggestions?